# Cell became Black of TableView in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using tableview in iOS. I am getting 10 element on array and after when i am last element on table i get more 10 element. Its work fine but some cell are overlap and black in colour.Cell overlap become normal after few second but black colour remain persist.I am newer in iOS. Please Help.

```
- (void)getNewMailFromBottom
{
    if (!isFinished && !isSideMenu && !searching) {
        NSInteger resultsSize = [foldersDataArray count];
        NSInteger count=0;
        NSMutableArray *tempMailArray = (NSMutableArray *)[NSArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)[dataBase getFolderMails:[mailBoxAccountId integerValue]:currentFolderLocalId:[foldersDataArray count]:10]];
        if ([tempMailArray count]==0 &&[appDelegate internetConnection] && [Globals getAuthenticationTicket] && ![[Globals getAuthenticationTicket] isEqualToString:@""] && ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"ALL_MAILS"] || [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"DEFAULT_MAILS"]) && currentFolderLocalId !=appDelegate.draftLocalId && currentFolderLocalId != appDelegate.localOutboxLocalId) {
            [self getAllFolderDataDetail :currentFolderId:YES];
        } else {
            for (NSDictionary *dict in tempMailArray) {
                if (![foldersDataArray containsObject:dict]) {
                    [foldersDataArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"mailDetail"]];
                    count++;
                }
            }
            NSMutableArray *arrayWithIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (NSInteger i = resultsSize; i < resultsSize + count; i++)
                [arrayWithIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
            [myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arrayWithIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [pullToRefreshManager tableViewReloadFinished];
        }
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell =[nib objectAtIndex:1];
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;



    NSInteger sectionsAmount = [tableView numberOfSections];
      NSInteger rowsAmount = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];

    if ([indexPath section] == sectionsAmount - 1 && [indexPath row] == rowsAmount-1) {
        NSLog(@"hello");

        [refreshBottomConnection cancel];
        [self getNewMailFromBottom];
        [pullToRefreshManager setPullToRefreshViewVisible:NO];    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i m posting code please check.

Comment: your cell height is dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   {
        double delayInSeconds = 0.30;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        [refreshBottomConnection cancel];
        [self getNewMailFromBottom];
      //  [pullToRefreshManager setPullToRefreshViewVisible:NO];

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Reusable Table Cell, and do editing on UITableView using

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and add condition for UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
       //Now you needn't
    }else if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert ){
        NSArray *insertIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath,nil];
        [self.list insertObject:@"new Cell" atIndex:row];//The list is the cell data source array
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
    }
}
```

As well as editing your cell view in this function:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your code. Please check below code.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell =[nib objectAtIndex:1];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

You are missing this last bracket...